# how to view delta log after creating table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have created table in delta format and not ingested any data .

just an empty table created and when I try using

```
DESCRIBE HISTORY table_name
```

it's showing:

> DESCRIBE HISTORY is only supported for Delta tables

even though my table is delta table

but if in ingest any data its work perfectly

Comment: can you show how have you created a table?

Comment: create table if not exists <tablename> .cols........using delta location (s3://....)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below syntax:

`DESCRIBE HISTORY table_identifier`

- table_identifier

  - [database_name.] table_name: A table name, optionally qualified with a database name.
  - delta.`<path-to-table>` : The location of an existing Delta table.

Refer: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#delta-history, https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-describe-history.html

Comment: but its not creating delta log until we write data that location , if the location is a s3 bucket.